# gravity not works in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I,m trying set the  gravity center,but not works. Here is my XML. What I,m doing wrong?

I attached image how XML now looks.

I,ve one root layout, I divided it two part , and I want every part has gravity center

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@color/bluefontcolor"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.developer.lucky.modernbalda.Flipmeter
                    android:id="@+id/scoreboard_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.developer.lucky.modernbalda.Flipmeter
                    android:id="@+id/scoreboard_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `Flipmeter` width is the problem, as they're set to fill the parent `LinearLayout` so they're rendered as wide as the parent (including the invisible part).

Try set their width to `wrap_content` or change their `layout_gravity` to `gravity` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/bluefontcolor"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.developer.lucky.modernbalda.Flipmeter
                android:id="@+id/scoreboard_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

             <com.developer.lucky.modernbalda.Flipmeter
                android:id="@+id/scoreboard_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: To center any member in the layout....the element should use wrap_content in dimensions and set gravity to center in parent

Answer (score 0):

Add below attribute in both Flipmeter

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

and also remove below attribute from both Flipmeter cause you have set width of LinearLayout to 0dp.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```